# Problema con While Loop

Tags: c++

Buenas estoy haciendo un "jueguito" donde el jugador control un PJ que tiene que evitar ser golpeado por unos trenes.
Estoy calculando las colisiones de manera constante con un while loop. Hasta ahí perfecto. El problema lo tengo cuando quiero restar un punto de vida el PJ por ser golpeado por el tren. A pesar de utilizar un bool para asegurar que mi PJ solo pierde un punto de vida, el programa le quita toda la vida que puede mientras se realiza el calculo de la colision. Aquí os dejo el codigo de la funcion en cuestion

```
void CheckTrainColisions(){
    bool dmgDone= false;

    while (shmPtr->isRunning)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < NUM_PERSONAJES; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TRENES; i++)
            {
                if (shmPtr->_trenes[i].posX == shmPtr->pj[k].posX && shmPtr->_trenes[i].posY == shmPtr >pj[k].posY && !dmgDone)
                {
                    dmgDone = true;
                    shmPtr->pj[k].gotHit = true;
                    shmPtr->pj[k].vid -= 1;
                }
            }
        }

        dmgDone = false;
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Tal vez al volver a poner a false la variable dmgDone dentro del bucle se cumple la condición para que el jugador pierda un punto. O tal vez tengas que salir del bucle while poniendo a false la condición de shmPtr->isRunning. Con el fragmento de código que pones, al menos yo no soy capaz de identificar otra cosa.

Answer (score 0):

No se porque pierde toda la vida, pero viendo la función entiendo que quieres comprobar si cada jugador ha sido golpeado y en caso de ser así que no pueda ser golpeado por otro tren en esa misma "jugada".

Si es así fíjate que cuando acabas de comprobar las posiciones X,Y y sales del bucle for interno no igualas dmgDone a false para el siguiente personaje, lo hacías una vez acaba de recorrer todos los personajes.

```
bool dmgDone= false;

while (shmPtr->isRunning) {
    for (int k = 0; k < NUM_PERSONAJES; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TRENES; i++) {
            if (checkPosition(shmPtr->pj[k], shmPtr->_trenes[i]) && !dmgDone) {
                dmgDone = true;
                shmPtr->pj[k].gotHit = true; // 
                shmPtr->pj[k].vid -= 1;
            }
        } // Aquí finaliza el for que comprueba cada personaje con todos los trenes
        dmgDone = false;
    }
}
```

Para evitar hacer todas las iteraciones una vez dmgDone vale true puedes añadir a la condición del for:
**(i < NUM_TRENES) && !dmgDone**

```
bool dmgDone= false;

while (shmPtr->isRunning) {
    for (int k = 0; k < NUM_PERSONAJES; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; (i < NUM_TRENES) && !dmgDone; i++) {
            
            if (checkPosition(shmPtr->pj[k], shmPtr->_trenes[i])) {
                dmgDone = true;
                shmPtr->pj[k].gotHit = true; // 
                shmPtr->pj[k].vid -= 1;
            }
        } // Aquí finaliza el for que comprueba cada personaje con todos los trenes
        dmgDone = false;
    }
}
```

De este modo la variable dmgDone no es necesaria en el if de las posiciones **checkPosition()**. Ahorrarás en tiempo de ejecución y será más fácil ver donde está el problema.

CheckPosition:

```
bool checkPosition(PJ p, Tren t) {
  if (t.posX == p.posX && t.posY == p.posY) {
    return true;
  }
 return false;
 }
```